# How to copy target file to a sub folder in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

In this Makefile- I want to copy the $(TGT) binary file after compiled to a sub folder(test) in the same directory. How can I include the copy command of the compiled target file in the Makefile?

```
    CC     = g++
    CFLAGS = -ansi -std=c++11 
    LIBS = -L/usr/lib -lstdc++

    DEPS = foo.cpp
    OBJ = foo.o

    TGT+=foo

    %.o: %.cc $(DEPS)
            $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@


    all: $(TGT)

    $(TGT): $(OBJ)
            $(CC) $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@

    # TODO: Need to include the copy command for copying TGT to test folder.

    clean:
            rm -f *.o $(TGT)
```

Currently the folder structure is-

```
<foo>
  Makefile
  foo.cpp
  foo.h
  <test>
       <..Need "foo" inside this folder>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there some reason you can't just change the recipe to copy the file?

Change:

```
$(TGT): $(OBJ)
        $(CC) $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@
```

To:

```
$(TGT): $(OBJ)
        $(CC) $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@
        cp $@ test
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want to make copy to more than one folder, then what should be the recipe be?

Comment: Well, you can surely add more `cp` commands?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Instead of maually specifying each folder. Can I declare a variable FLD= test deploy, and then access this variable as a recursion by writing a recipe for cp command.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't quite understand the question.  It's usually better, if you have a "bigger need", to specify that up front rather than asking about a trivial problem then using comments to continually add requirements.  Solutions for trivial problems may not be appropriate for more complex problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add a rule to copy a file:

```
all: test/$(TGT)

test/$(TGT): $(TGT)
        cp $< $@
```